# Ruby Active Record join with condition

Tags: ruby, join, activerecord

I have a column in the Tooltype table called "deleted" which can be true or false. I only want the records which are false. I somehow only manage to check for the second table (toolunits) but not for the first (tooltype). So this WOULD work if I had a column "deleted" in my toolunits table:

```
obj = Tooltype.joins(:toolunits).where(toolunits: {deleted: false}).distinct
```

But this does not (see third line):

```
get '/api/tooltypes' do
  if params['selector']
    obj = Tooltype.joins(:toolunits).where(tooltype: {deleted: false}).distinct
  else
    obj = Tooltype.joins(:toolunits).distinct
  end
  obj.get_list() do |q|
    if params['selector']
      q.where(deleted: false)
    end
  end.serialize.first
end
```

How can I use the condition on the first table?

Comment: `Tooltype.joins(:toolunits).where(deleted: false).distinct`

Comment: That's ambigous

Comment: I think you get an error for that

Comment: @Ursus Oh.... right. He has a `deleted` column in the other table.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking about two ways

```
Tooltype.joins(:toolunits).where(Tooltype.table_name => {deleted: false})

Tooltype.joins(:toolunits).where('tooltypes.deleted = ?', false)
```

Comment: I've just tested it to confirm. AR prepends the table name inside the `where` method when using a hash.

Comment: Yes but, which table name? In this query there's a join. So two table names.

Comment: It uses the table name of the calling class. Of course I tried in a query with a join and with a potentially conflicting name. I woudn't post it here otherwise

Comment: Ok, perfect. Make an answer so. That solution is obviously the simplest :)

Comment: No need. The OP must have gotten it by now. ;)